Problem installing slime
Installed SBCL, Emacs and quicklisp.  Wrote .emacs and stored it in my home folder.
M-x slime gives response: "no match".
checked that the file is really there.  Contents:
(load (expand-file-name "~/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
  ;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")


C-h f load says "Print messages at start and end of loading". What messages were printed?

Where and at what point should I type Ctrl-h f load?

Any time - it describes function load. And C-h k C-h f describes the command bound to C-h k.

You have to actually install slime. slime-helper.el merely configures it. Inside Emacs, run M-x list-packages. This will download a list of all available packages. Use / n to filter the list by name; type slime as the filter. Once you have found the package, type i to mark it for installation and x to execute.
